# Reset remote git branch

Tags: git

I have two remote branches in git, *master* and *test*. *master* reflects whatever will be deployed to our production environment next. *test* is the same, but for our testing environment.

Because of stalled or scrapped projects *test* could, over time, theoretically accumulate a lot of commits not present in *master*. How do I avoid this?

I know one solution would be to delete my local and remote *test* branch. Then create a new one based on *master* and push that to remote. However this approach forces my colleagues and build/deploy systems to also delete their local branches before pulling a the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach, allowing to pull the `test` branch is to reset the index of `test` to the one of `master`, not rewriting the history of `test`, but adding a new commit which would reflect the same state as `master`.
That would however leave in `test` history all the extra commits.

```
git checkout master
git merge -s ours test # make master believe that everything from test has been
                         merged to master up to this point.
git checkout test
git reset master -- . # reset the index content of test to the index of master
git checkout # reset the working tree of test to its new index
git commit -m "test reset to master"
git merge master # should be trivial merge
git push origin master
git push origin test
```